# Did the students at Hogwarts know what Snape did at the end of Half-Blood Prince?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, severus-snape

I know Harry's friends would have known, but did the other students know that

> Snape killed Dumbledore?

Did the rest of the wizarding world know about it?

Comment: It seems impossible that they *wouldn't*; even if McGonagall didn't make an announcement, it was definitely in the *Daily Prophet*

Comment: @Jason Baker Didn't some people and students believe Harry killed Dumbledore, since the rumor said he was seen that night at the top of the tower.

Comment: +1 for the "Spoiler" meme i hadn't read in more than 10 years.

Comment: @StephaneMathis Well, Rita Skeeter certainly made sure that some people did.

Answer (score 10):

**Some people definitely knew, but I don't think it was known to everybody.** (Rambling conjecture follows.)

Most of the teaching staff learnt at the end of *Half-Blood Prince*:

- Lupin, Tonks, Professor McGonagall and Madam Pomfrey were told that Snape killed Dumbledore at the end of *Half-Blood Prince*. Hermione and the Weasleys were in the ward, so learnt at the same time. Since Snape stunned Flitwick, he would have guessed as well.
- Later we see Hagrid and Professors Sprout, Flitwick and Slughorn enter Dumbledore's office, and they seem to know about the murder as well:

  > "Snape!" ejaculated Slughorn, who looked the most shaken, pale and sweating. "Snape! I taught him! I thought I knew him!"
  >
  > – *Half-Blood Prince*, chapter 29 (*The Phoenix Lament*)

Some other people might have known, or be able to guess:

- Members of the DA would have learnt (via Ginny) the truth about what happened at the top of the tower.
- Snape fled on the same night that Dumbledore was killed and Death Eaters broke into Hogwarts. Even if he didn't kill Dumbledore, many people would have guessed a relapse into old habits. I think there are plenty of Hogwarts parents who know Snape's past.
- A rumour that Dumbledore was killed by Snape (a teacher who he vouched for, and was a trusted ally) would be more shocking and salacious than if he was killed by a vanilla Death Eater. Even if it wasn't true, the nature of this rumour means it will spread faster. So there's a good chance some people know the truth, even if they don't realise it.

That said, I don't know how many *students* would know. I imagine quite a few of the parents – at least, those with connections to the magical world – would probably have heard rumours, but whether they tell their children is another matter.

Imagine you knew that the headmaster of your child's school had murdered the previous head. Would you tell your child? That will make them even more scared in an already oppressive and dangerous school environment. There will be some parents who don't tell their kids, and that means that not everybody will know.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer above, I would point to the exchange between Lupin and the trio in Grimmauld Place, where they discuss the 'party line' on why Harry Potter is wanted. Lupin passes a copy of the *Daily Prophet* to Harry:

> Harry smoothed out the paper. A huge photograph of his own face filled the front page. He read the headline over it:
>
> *WANTED FOR QUESTIONING ABOUT THE DEATH OF ALBUS DUMBLEDORE*
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.171 - Bloomsbury - chapter 11, *The Bribe*

And, even before that, there's the interview with Rita Skeeter:

> *'Well, I don't want to say too much - it's all in the book - but eye witnesses inside Hogwarts Castle saw Potter running away from the scene moments after Dumbledore fell, jumped or was pushed. Potter later gave evidence against Severus Snape, a man against whom he has a notorious grudge. Is everything as it seems? That is for the wizarding community to decide - once they've read my book.'*
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.29 - Bloomsbury - chapter 2, *In Memoriam*

So, as well as Rita Skeeter's tabloid journalism, there was an official effort to absolve Severus Snape of the crime. So, anybody who followed the official, government line (or whose parents followed it) would certainly have been made to doubt that Snape was responsible.

At the same time, Skeeter acknowledges the 'theory' that Snape was the murderer, so anybody who read that interview in the *Prophet* would have certainly heard that rumour. And the way she talks about it casually makes it sound like it had been 'doing the rounds'. However, it does seem that she goes on to doubt it.

So, I think the answer is that most people would probably have heard Snape blamed for Dumbledore's death. But there was a real and concerted government effort to transfer blame away from him. And then there was Rita Skeeter's meddlings. Exactly what average Joe Hogwarts student thought is hard to say. Given the events of *The Order of the Phoenix* it's not hard to imagine plenty of people having their doubts that Snape did it. But at the same time I've little doubt the DA, all Gryffindor seventh years and plenty of others believed it was Snape.